# tabbed navigation in tableview section header

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, code-reuse

I'd like to mimic the behavior of profile page of pinterest app.

You can tab on Boards/Pins/Likes(tableview section header) and, tableview changes accordingly.

Below are screenshots to illustrate this.
[image]
[image]

Suppose I can create each of the tabs(boards/pins/likes) in separate viewController.
Also suppose I want to reuse the code of each viewController because other views(such as 'following' tab on the tab bar) look very much like one of them(boards/pins/likes).

How would I share a table header & table section header and also separate codes enough so that I can reuse bulk of them?

Basically, I have two viewControllers with tableview.
Now I want to create a new viewController with a tableView header/section header that user will tab to see one of the previous two viewController's view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the tab appear in Table Header, instead it might be a view subclassing `UISegmentedControl`. If you want to reuse it you can create the interface in xib file and link it with your view controller

try check this github project https://github.com/rs/SDSegmentedControl for custom UISegmentedControl

Comment: I think it's tableSectionHeader because it sticks around when user pull down the page.

Comment: there are so many ways to achieve the effect, as for myself I made a similar one using `UIsegmentedControl`then put the 'tableVIew' inside 'ViewController', it serve its purpose